Create a custom control that automatically adds new properties to the another control when adding that custom control to the designer
I want to create a custom control like a picker in Winform. When I select a value of the picker, the other textboxes will be set to the corresponding value. For example, the picker is Product. After selecting a Product, ProductName and ProductPrice can be set into the specified textboxes.
I have an idea to create a custom control that when I add it to the Form, the Textboxes in Form will automatically have a new attribute "picker" added and I can enter a field from Picker into it. . If you have ever worked with GrapeCity's GcShortCut then you will understand that it is possible. but I really don't know what to do.
If anyone knows please let me know. Or if you have any other ideas please let me know. thank you very much

I tried looking for results on Google but I can't think of what the keyword is?

IExtenderProvider + ControlDesigner -- Maybe you can just use databindings

Property extenders are a design-time feature. At runtime you can either work with data bindings and view models or you can use events like TextChanged, ItemSelected or Validated. Data binding usually leads to better and simpler code than event handling; however, you need to invest in learning.
